# Default value on user profile property

Tags: 2010, user-profile

Is it possible to set a default value on a user profile property? Eg a term?
I guess one has to hook up with a user profile creation event, but I can't find this one.

A workaround could be to add another property, hidden, and run a periodic timerjob to set a value and set the 'default' value to the first property. When running the timerjob the next time, check if the hidden property contains a value set by the timerjob before, which means the 'default' property has already been set, skip this one and proceed with the next one to check if the user profile is created in the time interval between running the timerjobs. 
I don't this is performance wise a good idea (with a lot of users).

What do you think? Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a good way to do this.

You can manually provision the user profiles and set the field.  This of course could be difficult to manage, and might conflict with some of the user profile sync activities that are needed for purposes other than provisioning.

Instead of the hidden property/timer job route, a cleaner path might be to use a powershell script that is executed via a scheduled task.  My blog is down right now, but I recently linked to a script that could search for profiles without a property value and then iterate through there and set the value.  Here is the link, its been like russian roulette though to get it to load.  :(  http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/bulk-updates-of-user-profile-properties

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was lucky in the roulette! The script is able to set a default property which can be scheduled. But what if the user already set a value on this property. In that case I don't want to update the property, but leave the value which the user set. I don't think the script provides in this situation.

Comment: This is why Mike specified to only set it for profiles without a property value.

Answer (score -1):

Work a round I used in a project was to set a default value in the FIM client, below the steps to configure:

You can set a default value in the FIM client:

- On the server running the User Profile Synchronization Service, open miisclient.exe (Located at Drive:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell)
- Click on the “Management Agents” tab
- There should be a management agent in the list that represents your synchronization connection. For Active Directory synchronization connections, the management agent will have the name MOSSAD-YourSynchConnectionName . Double click on the management agent that represents your synchronization connection
- Click on “Configure Attribute Flow”
- In this screen you see all properties and it is possible to bind a 'constant' to a user profile property.

---

This work around will work, but it is important to note it will leave you with a User Profile Service which is in an unsupported state. According to Spence Harbar the following applies

> **Forefront Identity Manager** 
>   A bundled version of FIM that includes two
>   Windows Services, and associated configuration and data. It is not
>   supported to use the FIM client tool but this can be useful for
>   viewing progress and identifying errors. The two FIM services are
>   configured by the User Profile Synchronization Service SharePoint
>   Service

[Blog post by Spence](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

In other words, leave the configuration of FIM to SharePoint, anything you cannot configure through the SharePoint UI or object model is not a supported config change for FIM.

Comment: Unsupported state: that's not what one wants... Other suggestions?